# Draw Script value to other script unity Editor scripting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a script A in it i have a variable name IntValue and my script B is fully empty, i have made a EditorScript name myEditor how can i Draw Script A Data to Script B
i have tried everything like first making a reference in script B to that variable and try to access in my editor script but then i can't use serializedObject.FindProperty() it's return null data, asked chatgpt and other source but no luck please help me there has to be a way to do it right?

this is what chatgpt have done.

Script A

```
public class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int IntValue;
}
```

Script B

```
public class ScriptB : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Editor Script

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(ScriptB))]
public class MyEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty dataValueProperty;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // Find the serialized property of the dataValue variable in Script A
        dataValueProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("IntValue");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // Update the serialized object
        serializedObject.Update();

        // Draw the default inspector GUI for Script B
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        // Access the dataValue property from Script A
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(dataValueProperty);

        // Apply modifications to the serialized object
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Comment: If your `ScriptB` is completely empty .. then where should the reference to the instance of your `ScriptA` come from ...?

Comment: You didn't read my question properly like my Script A have a int variable and I just want to draw that int variable to my empty Script B with editor Scripting

Comment: I read that ... but where do you get the reference to scriptA from? How is your editor script supposed to know which scriptA instance you want to get the field value from?

Comment: yes that is my question that's what i'm trying to find out how can i get a reference to **ScriptA** while making a editor script for **ScriptB**
if you like to discuss more we can find a suitable chatting channel

Comment: well you can't ... again: Where is this reference supposed to come from? What exactly are you trying to achieve an why do you think you need this?

Comment: what do you mean you can't, reference should come from ScriptA and render it's value to ScriptB. what i'm trying to achieve that i have 10 or say 20 scripts they all have so many variables i just want to get 1 script and render it's data to ScriptB

Comment: you can't have "one script" .. what is that supposed to be? You can have an **instance** of a script .. but then you still need a **reference** to it somehow ...  It sounds like you would rather want to use a `ScriptableObject`, set your values here and then reference this in multiple places ... see https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html and https://gamedevbeginner.com/scriptable-objects-in-unity/

Comment: i can't use scriptableObject anyways thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a reference to ScriptA in your editor, create a new SerializedObject.

```
var scriptASerializedObject = new UnityEditor.SerializedObject(scriptA);
```

Use this serialized object to get the IntValue field.

```
var intValue = scriptASerializedObject.FindProperty("IntValue");
```

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand i tried your code and it's giving me error at **scriptA** where are you getting this reference
please explain more in detail
`SerializedObject(*scriptA*);`

Comment: I dont know how your references are set up (wasn't included in your question), that is why I left it to you to get the reference.  If you were to go into detail on your setup, we can either specify how to get the reference or recommend a different approach.  Please add any new details to your question, not as comments.